# How to deal with class composition when components cannot be accessed from the outside?

Tags: c#, class, oop, uml, composition

For example if I say I have three classes `A`, `B`, and `C` where `B` and `C` have a composition relation ship with `A`. That means the life of `B` and `C` is handled by `A`, and also B and C cannot access directly from the outside.

For some reason my `DataService` class needs to return objects of `B` and `C` as It cant return a object of `A` as `B` and `C` cannot be initialized at the same time. (to be able to initialize`C` you have to initialize`B` first).

So that I'm returning  `DataTables` from `DataService` and then inside the class `A` those data tables are converted to `B` / `C` objects.

1. If `B` and `C` objects cannot be initialized at the same time is it valid to say that `B` and `C` have a composition relationship with `A`?
2. If its composition is it must to generate `A` with `B` and `C` inside?
3. What is the proper way to handle this sort of a problem?

**EDIT:**

Following code explains the way I'm doing it now with DataTables.

Example:

```
class A   
{  
    private List<B> B;
    private List <C> C;

    public A()
    {
        B= new List<B>();
        C= new List<C>();
    }

    public List<B> GetB( DataTable dt) 
    {
        // Create a B list from dt
        return B;
    }
}


class Presenter
{
  private void Show B()
  {
    _View.DataGrid = A.GetB(DataService.GetAListOfB());
  }
}
```

The actual scenario is I have a class called `WageInfo` and classes `Earning` and `Deduction` having a composition relationship in the design. But for you to generate `Deductions` first you should Generate `earnings` and should be saved in a table. Then only you can generate `deductions` for the `earnings` to calculate balance wages.

Also note that these contained classes have a one to many relationship with the containing class WageInfo. So actually WageInfo has a `List<Earnings>` and `List<Deduction>`

My initial question was, is it ok if my `DataService` class returns  `Deductions` / `Earnings` objects (actually lists) not a `WageInfo`?

Still not clear?

Comment: Too many letters, I'm already lost. Could you try splitting it up or clarifying a bit?

Comment: This reads like three separate questions.

Comment: I have no idea what is being asked here.

Comment: Guys, how could it be more clear? If `A` is available but not `B` and `C`, how does `A` create `B`, but not `C`, but when `B` is created, `C` needs to be created, but not by `A`. Then `A` needs to return `B` or `C`, but not `B` and `C` and `B` can't return `C`, but `C` can return `B` and `A`, but only if `C` was created not by `A` or by `B`. Understand now? (note my sarcasm, by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If `A` has `B` and `C`, it's a composition, assuming that neither `B` nor `C` can "live" on their own. The time at which `B` and `C` are created does not play into it.
2. `A` does not have to create `B` and `C` in order for it to be a composition. These could be given to it from the outside at the time when `A` is constructed, assuming that they are given a proper context. For example, if `B` and `C` need a reference back to `A`, then whoever creates them needs to provide `A`, or `A` could take ownership when `B` and `C` are added to it.
3. To make it easier to handle problems like this, create interfaces for the portions of `B` and `C` that you want to be usable on the outside. Unlike the classes `B` and `C`, the interfaces must be able to stand on its own, i.e. be meaningful with or without the context of object `A`.

The interfaces in #3 are important, because your data service wants to return `B` and `C`. Returning them without an interface has a high potential of violating encapsulation, because presumably some of `B`s and `C`s functionality is relevant only in the context of `A`, and the context of `A` is missing on the caller's side.

Comment: To point 2... Composition means an "exclusive ownership", in contrast to aggregation, which is "shared". This means that B and C could be manipulated (including instantiation) solely by A. Otherwise, if B and C could be created from outside and then passed around before ending up in B, it would be be an aggregation.

Comment: @Aleks `B` and `C` could be created by a factory class that also makes `A`s, and be given to `A` at the time it is constructed.

Comment: Hmmmm, sounds kind of strange and does not change the fact that the 3rd entity knows how to construct inner parts of A... Besides, B and C can be added anytime after A is constructed. So, should A talk to this factory every time and request a new B? I find it a lot cleaner and safer to delegate this responsability to A and its addB(params) method.

Comment: @Aleks If `B` and `C` could be added after `A`'s construction, it's an aggregation. I think that `A.addB` method disqualifies the relationship between `A` and `B` as composition, making it an aggregation. 3rd entity that knows how to make `B`s could be LINQ2SQL or NHibernate; the fact that they instantiate `B` and `C` for `A`'s use does not by itself disqualify the relation from being a composition.

Comment: A.addB() does not "kill" the composition. :) Take the example of Invoice --> InvoiceItem. InvoiceItem makes no sense out of Invoice and can definitelly be added to it during the preparation of the Invoice (that is, after its creation). During whole this time the Invoice structure is growing, Items always added through addItem() and neatly controlled by Invoice itself. And this is definitelly a composition. LINQ2SQL or NHibernate are on another level of abstraction and should not be mixed in this story. We discuss the logic of UML relationship and not how it is implemented.